# React-mention suggestion box not positioning correctly

Tags: reactjs, next.js, frontend

I'm using the react-mention library to build a mention component in my React application. The component works fine, but I'm having an issue with the positioning of the suggestion box.

Currently, the suggestion box is showing at the position of the last mention input, instead of the current input where the user is typing. This is causing confusion for users who expect the suggestion box to show up where they are typing.

I have this css for `MentionInput`'s  `style` props:

```
export default {
  control: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap',
  },
  '&multiLine': {
    input: {
      border: 'none',
      outline: 'none',
      resize: 'none',
    },
  },
  suggestions: {
    '&:scrollbar': {
      display: 'none',
    },
    maxHeight: '250px',
    overflow: 'auto',
    borderRadius: '10px',
    list: {
      color: 'black',
      fontSize: '12px',
      wordWrap: 'break-word',
    },
    item: {
      padding: '5px 15px',
      borderBottom: '1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.15)',
    },
  },
}
```